# Linear Layout Overlapping Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I can not figure out for the life of me why and how to stop the **Linear Layout** from overlapping the **navigation bar**. I am familiar with Android Studio, just not version 2+.

This problem was never a thing and I have tried multiple searches and attempts to fix this. (Screenshot below).

[image: Nav bar overlapped by layout]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `LinearLayout` code in the `content_main.xml` file.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `LinearLayout`  set padding top `50dp`

```
android:paddingTop="50dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
```

You can change margin values depending on layout position.